# Android MapFragment :Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-maps-v2

I have a horizontal list of images, when I click on an image it loads a dialog fragment.The dialog fragment contains a ViewPager. The view pager loads a MapFragment inside the PagerAdapter. here is how I do it,

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        final LoyaltyOutlet outlet = data.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop_item, collection, false);
        TextView address = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_ShopAddress);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.shopMap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(outlet.getLattitude(), outlet.getLongitude())).title(
                        outlet.getOutletName());
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(outlet.getLattitude(), outlet.getLongitude()), 10);
                googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }
        });
//        GoogleMap googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.shopMap)).getMap();

        address.setText(outlet.getOutletName() +"\n"+outlet.getOutletBulding()+" "+outlet.getOutletStreet()+"\n"+outlet.getOutletLocality());

        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;

    }
```

Here is the scenario I have. Initially when the screen is loaded with horizontal list of images, I tap on an image to load the DialogFragment with map. On initial load it works fine. Now if I load the same Dialog fragment again I get an error where it inflates the layout inside instantiateItem,

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error
>   inflating class fragment

Here is the fragment_shop_item.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <com.mobytz.utils.CustomFontTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/txt_ShopAddress"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                attrs:customFont="handy_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/android:black"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".75">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/shopMap"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Not sure whats going wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the fragment_shop_item.xml?

Comment: @Dani . Updated my question. Thanks